# Adding meta tags on Google Sites

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags, google-sites-2016

Apologies if advance if the questions here are too basic as I am new to web development and SEO. I have a website built on google sites and trying to improve SEO rankings using meta tags. I have figured out how to write up a meta tag. For example, the following:

```
<meta name="title" content="pomorobotics.com">
<meta name="description" content="Unsure how to work with robots? We can help. Specializing in robotic systems integration, end of arm tooling and industry 4.0 solutions. Get in touch!">
<meta name="keywords" content="Robots, Robotics, Collaborative, End of Arm Tooling, End Effectors, Automation, Systems Integration, Digital Twin, Digitisation, Industry 4.0, Solutions, Turnkey, Robotic Solutions, Engineering">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="pomorobotics">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
<meta name="application-url" itemprop="url" content="www.pomorobotics.com/home">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="language" content="English">
```

Google Sites only gives me the option to Embed code, would the meta tags be functional if I was to insert this script customised per page? I am thinking of adding the code as top of the website as possible - either adjacent to the Title or heading blocks. I've attached an image showing where I have the meta tag script embedded as a block

Answer (score 1):

The new version of Google Sites does not offer the ability to edit the meta keywords and description tags as no search engine uses them, so there's no longer any point in their existence.

Comment: I agree that Google sites doesn't let you set them and that Google doesn't use meta keywords for search.  However, Google does us the meta description occasionally in search results and other search engines may still use keywords.

Comment: It's standard these days to have tags as many other platforms and social media use the tags for preview.

Answer (score -1):

the only solution I found for, create a google my business account and add your domain to it, after the all confirmation processes google will let you put in the title and description as your own

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiwk4_8rqv7AhVjDrcAHcuRB7kQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen_lk%2Fbusiness%2F&usg=AOvVaw09GPIMa8KhRrjRwkkNr8wj

Comment: Please review your phrasing. The unusual punctuation, the switching between "my account" and "your account", the "the all" phrasing confuses me so much that I do not really get what you are trying to say. It is however important, because that unreadable part (i.e. the one which is not only a link) needs to provide the solution. Otherwise this is a link-only answer and should be deleted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).